# How do I add column sort functionality to my table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have tried now for a couple of hours to add sort functionality on a react-virtualized table, but can't get my head around it... here is the [example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table) and [source code](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Table/Table.example.js). Sorry, I was not able to create a plnkr, so I have attached a link to my github [repo](https://github.com/isaklafleur/autoMDM/blob/master/client/src/components/PartTable.js).

I get this error, when I submit the form with a input text SCREW for example:

```
TypeError: list.sortBy is not a function
    at PartTable._sortList (PartTable.js:136)
    at new PartTable (PartTable.js:18)
```

In the example on the [site](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table) they uses context (`const { list } = this.context;`) instead of props. Maybe this is the issue?

When I console log `this.props.list` I get the correct list (see the two example documents)

```
_sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    const { list } = this.props;

    // console.log(list);

    return list
      .sortBy(item => item[sortBy])
      .update(
        list => (sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? list.reverse() : list)
      );
  }
```

Here are two objects coming from my server and into `props.list`

```
[
  {
    customsTariff: "73181568",
    facility: "SDC",
    netWeight: "0,07",
    partName: "CAPSCREW",
    partNumber: "3121210233",
    __v: 0,
    _id: "59a9429ac0b7467bf084eb6e"
  },
  {
    customsTariff: "73481568",
    facility: "SDC",
    netWeight: "0,08",
    partName: "CAPSCREW2",
    partNumber: "3121210333",
    __v: 0,
    _id: "59a9429ac0b7463bf084eb6e"
  }
];
```

**Here is the code from PartTable.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { AutoSizer, Column, Table } from "react-virtualized";
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import SortDirection from "./SortDirection";
import SortIndicator from "./SortIndicator";
import Checkbox from "material-ui/Checkbox";
import "react-virtualized/styles.css";
import "../../styles/App.css";
import styles from "./Table.example.css";

export default class PartTable extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const sortBy = "partNumber"; // I want to sort by partNumber by default
    const sortDirection = SortDirection.ASC;
    const sortedList = this._sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection });

    this.state = {
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      rowCount: 1000,
      sortedList
    };
    this._noRowsRenderer = this._noRowsRenderer.bind(this);
    this._generateCheckbox = this._generateCheckbox.bind(this);
    this._sort = this._sort.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.props.list);
    const { sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList } = this.state;
    const rowGetter = ({ index }) => this._getDatum(sortedList, index);
    const { list, headers } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
          {({ width }) => (
            <Table
              width={width}
              height={500}
              headerHeight={50}
              rowHeight={50}
              rowCount={list.length}
              rowGetter={rowGetter}
              noRowsRenderer={this._noRowsRenderer}
              sort={this._sort}
              sortBy={sortBy}
              sortDirection={sortDirection}
            >
              {headers.map(header => {
                return (
                  <Column
                    key={header.id}
                    label={header.label}
                    dataKey={header.id}
                    disableSort
                    width={100}
                    flexGrow={1}
                    cellRenderer={
                      header.index ? this._generateCheckbox : undefined
                    }
                  />
                );
              })}
            </Table>
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
        <CSVLink data={list}>
          <Button color="accent">Export {list.length} records to CSV</Button>
        </CSVLink>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _noRowsRenderer() {
    return <div>No Parts here...</div>;
  }
  _generateCheckbox(event) {
    // console.log(event);
    return (
      <div className="table-check-box">
        {this.props.activeCheckboxes && (
          <Checkbox
            onChange={() => this.props._activeCheckbox(event.rowData._id)}
            checked={this.props.activeCheckboxes.includes(event.rowData._id)}
          />
        )}
        {event.cellData}
      </div>
    );
  }
  _isSortEnabled() {
    const { list } = this.props;
    const { rowCount } = this.state;
    return rowCount <= list.size;
  }

  _getDatum(list, index) {
    return list.get(index % list.size);
  }

  _sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    const sortedList = this._sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection });

    this.setState({ sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList });
  }

  _sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    const { list } = this.props;

    // console.log(list);

    return list
      .sortBy(item => item[sortBy])
      .update(
        list => (sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? list.reverse() : list)
      );
  }
  _rowClassName({ index }) {
    if (index < 0) {
      return styles.headerRow;
    } else {
      return index % 2 === 0 ? styles.evenRow : styles.oddRow;
    }
  }
}

PartTable.PropTypes = {
  list: PropTypes.arrayOf({}).isRequired,
  activeCheckboxes: PropTypes.arrayOf({}),
  _activeCheckbox: PropTypes.func,
  headers: PropTypes.arrayOf({}.isRequired)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that your code has references to `list.length`- it seems like the `list` prop you're accepting might be an Array? The `sortBy` method (assuming you lifted this from the react-virtualized docs) belongs to an [Immutable JS `List`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List). To sort a JavaScript Array you'll want to use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

PS. The code you pasted has a couple of other references to `List` methods (eg `list.get(index)`) that you'll want to replace with brackets (eg `list[index]`) if I'm correct that you're using an Array.

**Full code solution for PartTable.js**
(Provided by author)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import {
  AutoSizer,
  Column,
  Table,
  SortDirection,
  SortIndicator
} from "react-virtualized";
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Checkbox from "material-ui/Checkbox";
import "react-virtualized/styles.css";
import "../../styles/App.css";
import styles from "./Table.example.css";

export default class PartTable extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const sortBy = "partNumber";
    const sortDirection = SortDirection.ASC;
    const sortedList = this._sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection });

    this.state = {
      list: this.props.list,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      sortedList,
      rowCount: 1000
    };
    this._noRowsRenderer = this._noRowsRenderer.bind(this);
    this._generateCheckbox = this._generateCheckbox.bind(this);
    this._sort = this._sort.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { headers } = this.props;
    const { list, sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList, rowCount } = this.state;

    const rowGetter = ({ index }) => this._getDatum(sortedList, index);

    return (
      <div>
        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
          {({ width }) => (
            <Table
              width={width}
              height={500}
              headerHeight={50}
              rowHeight={50}
              rowClassName={this._rowClassName}
              rowCount={rowCount}
              rowGetter={({ index }) => list[index]} // ({ index }) => list[index]
              noRowsRenderer={this._noRowsRenderer}
              onHeaderClick={this._sortByClickedHeader}
              sort={this._sort}
              sortBy={sortBy}
              sortDirection={sortDirection}
            >
              {headers.map(header => {
                return (
                  <Column
                    key={header.id}
                    label={header.label}
                    dataKey={header.id}
                    width={100}
                    flexGrow={1}
                    cellRenderer={
                      header.index ? this._generateCheckbox : undefined
                    }
                  />
                );
              })}
            </Table>
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
        <CSVLink data={list}>
          <Button color="accent">Export {list.length} records to CSV</Button>
        </CSVLink>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _getDatum(list, index) {
    return list[index];
  }

  _sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    const sortedList = this._sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection });

    this.setState({ sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList });
  }

  _sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    const { list } = this.props;
    if (sortBy) {
      let updatedList =
        // sort by name
        list.sort(function(a, b) {
          var nameA = a[sortBy].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
          var nameB = b[sortBy].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
          if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
          }
          // names must be equal
          return 0;
        });
      sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC
        ? updatedList.reverse()
        : updatedList;
    }
  }

  _noRowsRenderer() {
    return <div>No Parts here...</div>;
  }
  _generateCheckbox(event) {
    // console.log(event);
    return (
      <div className="table-check-box">
        {this.props.activeCheckboxes && (
          <Checkbox
            onChange={() => this.props._activeCheckbox(event.rowData._id)}
            checked={this.props.activeCheckboxes.includes(event.rowData._id)}
          />
        )}
        {event.cellData}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PartTable.PropTypes = {
  list: PropTypes.arrayOf({}).isRequired,
  activeCheckboxes: PropTypes.arrayOf({}),
  _activeCheckbox: PropTypes.func,
  headers: PropTypes.arrayOf({}.isRequired)
};
```